# autotools or cmake for compiling C

Tags: c, autotools

Does autotools comes out of box for all the major unix systems? I am looking for something that can compile the code without installing any additional software and platform independent(UNIX flavors and Architecture).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*Autotools* needs to be installed only on the *developer*'s system, and not on the *builder*'s system. Their output is an independent sh script that will create the desired Makefile. In some cases though (e.g. "automagic" dependencies), also the builder may need *autotools*, and it's not uncommon a specific version is required.

*autotools* is basically a giant collection of scripted obscure kludges, driven by directive files to be written in an even more obscure macro language - [m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/). If you see any remote chance your project will be cross-compiled, then steer away from *autotools* and its siblings (read *libtool*).

*cmake* is a much better alternative, but there are even better and leaner programs like [scons](http://www.scons.org/).

Still, I have to admit that most Unix systems today are mostly ANSI C and POSIX compliant as opposed to 10+ years ago, that is, the time *autotools* was conceived. I hardly see the need of anything but the classic *make* to be able to compile your project in a portable way.

Comment: Using a standard make file would only work if dependent libraries where installed in standard places. I usually build and install many of my own libraries because the distro's I use do not keep up to date enough. A make file that could find various location for say mysql libs would be a nightmare to maintain

Comment: +1 POSIX systems have `getconf` that let you inspect the POSIX configuration variables from scripts.

Comment: @adrian-cornish I often cross-compile, and nothing is in a standard place, not even libc. Still, I don't find it difficult to manage everything with a single Makefile (actually, it is *simple*; the real nightmare comes when I am forced to deal with things like autotools, which are nothing but simple). Having said that, no tools will automagically find libraries in odd places; you need some form of configuration one way or another.

Comment: It is highly misleading to claim that autotools would require a separate package be installed, or that finding the right version is a major problem if you are creating a package.  The right version is whatever version you choose, and the end user does not have to worry about installing any version of autotools because the package you distribute is a complete stand-alone thing.  (This distinguishes it sharply from most other build tools which DO require the end user to install additional software.)

Comment: @Porculus is exactly right: Autotools is needed on the *source system* where *you* build *your* source tarball and *not on any of the deployment systems* which is in sharp contrast to cmake.  The other point that this answer gets wrong is that sometimes you actually need to test for things (eg where headers are, which of several possible libraries is present etc) which make cannot do.  Different tools for different use case.

Comment: @porculus You are right, I edited my answer. The "configure" script is typically all you need on the build system, but that it not always the case for complex builds where the user may select optional features and libraries.

Comment: @dirk-eddelbuettel Testing for things like libraries is a flawed philosophy in a build system. You assume that a) the user is clueless and does not know what software they have and b) it assumes that you can run compiled software. The latter is definitely wrong when cross compiling.

Comment: @SquareRootOfTwentyThree: Firstly, a tool supposed to simplify finding libraries in odd places is `pkg-config`. Sadly, many libraries still don't provide .pc files for it. Secondly, I don't believe that SCons can be friendly in any way for people cross-compiling. To be honest, I don't remember seeing a single `SConstruct` file which I didn't have to patch because it either ignored my `CC`/`CXX`, `CFLAGS` or `LDFLAGS`. That said, autotools *are* friendly, if you use them properly.

Comment: @SquareRootOfTwentyThree: Makefiles cannot differentiate between competing implementation, say MPICH2 or OpenMPI for MPI.  Makefiles cannot tell whether you have a sufficiently recent version.

Comment: @michal-gorny My personal statistics is that 80% of all autotools's configure scripts I had to deal with are totally broken when it comes to cross-compiling. Most of them require target code to be executed on the host, which is obviously a no-no.

Comment: @SquareRootOfTwentyThree: and how is either CMake or SCons superior here? Do you suggest that people stop doing wrong things when given a more flexible tool?

Comment: @dirk-eddelbuettel I interpreted the question as simply being about a normal program that needs to be portable across several Unix OS. autotools is totally unnecessary these days *for that*. A Makefile is plenty sufficient. When it comes to sophisticated selection of libraries in a system (as you bring as example), I don't personally think it's blasphemy to ask the user to edit the Makefile, especially because I am biased toward cross-compiling environments as you can tell. Where inconvenient, I would suggest cmake/scons and not autotools since autotools is simply a pain to control.

Comment: @michal-gorny I am saying it takes 1/10th of the time to troubleshoot and fix scons scripts when they derail, since they are way more readable. Fixing autotools script is a total nightmare (for me at least).

Answer (score 3):

If you use autotools correctly, the end result is a script `configure` so that

```
 configure
 make
 make install
```

works -- and yes, the very point of autotools is that this should work just about everywhere.

Comment: And if you end up hating autotools, you're not alone.

Answer (score 0):

I have used both recently and overall I prefer cmake over autotools. I found cmake a little simpler with less scripting needed. Most linux distros will include a package for both although cmake make have to be installed as an option.

Autotools are ok for simple projects but in my experience they required lots and lots of extra scripting when checking libraries etc - cmake on the other hand made it simple to detect dependencies. Also a plus you may not care about - but it make compiling your code on windows platforms easier as well